# Button in the center of a card footer in Bootstraps

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this `.card-footer`:

```
<div class="card-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-theme pull-left" type="button" id="toleft"><</button>
    <button class="btn btn-theme" type="button" id="more">+</button>
    <button class="btn btn-theme pull-right" type="button" id="toright">></button>
</div>
```

The buttons `.toleft` and `.toright` are in the correct position, however the button `#more` should be exactly on the center of the footer, but it is still on the left.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you possibly referencing Bootstrap v3 CSS?  `.card` is a Bootstrap 4 component.  See below for my example using Bootstrap 4 CSS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Bootstrap 3**

You can use the following solution adding [`.text-center`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment) to the `.card-footer` container:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card-footer text-center">
  <button class="btn btn-theme pull-left" type="button" id="toleft">&lt;</button>
  <button class="btn btn-theme" type="button" id="more">+</button>
  <button class="btn btn-theme pull-right" type="button" id="toright">&gt;</button>
</div>
```

---

**Bootstrap 4.0+**

On Bootstrap 4.0+ there is [no class `.pull-left` or `.pull-right` anymore](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/migration/#utilities). You have to use [`.float-left` and `.float-right`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/float/#classes) instead. You can also use `.text-center` to center the second button.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="card-footer text-center">
  <button class="btn btn-dark float-left" type="button" id="toleft">&lt;</button>
  <button class="btn btn-dark" type="button" id="more">+</button>
  <button class="btn btn-dark float-right" type="button" id="toright">&gt;</button>
</div>
```

---

> **Note:** I don't recommend to use custom CSS rules. Bootstrap is a CSS Framework to provide solutions for many design problems. Overwriting CSS properties on components can cause problems.

Answer (score 3):

**If you're seeing this in 2018 or beyond, please note that some of these old answers will not work with Bootstrap 4**...

However, there is no need to include additional CSS as a couple of the previous answers suggest.

The `pull-left` and `pull-right` classes no longer work in Bootstrap 4.

Instead, we now use `float-left` and `float-right` to float our left and right buttons.

The easiest way to achieve the desired effect would be to start by centering the footer contents by adding the `text-center` class to the footer.

Next, we can float the left button with the `float-left` class and float the right button with the `float-right` class.

Here's the final HTML:

```
<div class="card-footer text-center">
<button class="btn btn-theme float-left" type="button" id="toleft">left</button>
<button class="btn btn-theme" type="button" id="more">center</button>
<button class="btn btn-theme float-right" type="button" id="toright">right</button>
</div>
```

Which gives us the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just tried this with the latest alpha6 build of Bootstrap 4 (I'm assuming you're using BS4 as you mentioned the card component), and it looks as though the default behaviour is to align buttons in card footers to the middle anyway.

Note that I also had to introduce the `.pull-left` / `.pull-right` utility classes, as these no longer appear to be defined in the Bootstrap CSS.

See demo below:

```css
.pull-left {
  float: left;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header">
    Featured
  </div>
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer text-muted">
    <button class="btn btn-theme pull-left" type="button" id="toleft">&lt;</button>
    <button class="btn btn-theme" type="button" id="more">+</button>
    <button class="btn btn-theme pull-right" type="button" id="toright">&gt;</button> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```css
.card-footer{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="card-footer">
     <button class="btn btn-theme pull-left" type="button" id="toleft"><</button>
     <button class="btn btn-theme" type="button" id="more">+</button>
     <button class="btn btn-theme pull-right" type="button" id="toright">></button>
 </div>
```